# Rails: route constrains if records found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to constrain my routes if a match is found in the `params` like so:

```
constraints :client_code => User.all.client_code.any? do
  get ":client_code" => "share#index", :as => :shares
  get ":client_code/:id" => "share#show", :as => :share
end
```

What should go instead of `User.all.client_code.any?`? I really cannot figure it out.

Thanks! **UPDATE**

I've made a constraints object like so:

```
class ClientCodeConstraint
  def initialize
    @users = User.all
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @users.where(:client_code => request).first
  end
end
```

And changed the `constraints ...` line in `routes.rb` to this:

```
 constraints ClientCodeConstraint.new do ...
```

Am I on the right track? I'm getting this response:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Array:...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this method, don't know how efficient it is though:

```
def matches?(request)
  @users.each do |user|
    return true if request.path_parameters[:client_code] == user.client_code
  end
end
```